# How to maintain space between table and header in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, format

I am working on SSRS Report, [image]

But on other page this distance is not maintained. Any way to resolve this?

Comment: have you found the solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the space into the Page Header section.

So if (for example) your Page Header is completely occupied by a text box, extend the bottom of the page header down so that there is now a gap between the bottom of the text box and the end of the page header, and move the table up so that the top of the table is flush with the end of the page header - like so:

[image]

Comment: This is one work around for this specific issue, but what if we can't afford to waste any of the printable area ?

my problem is using header with border line on the bottom

Answer (score -1):

Header repeat in every page 
so you can add empty textbox in the end  header and fill it color white [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMFnP.png)